# Springboot and ServoBlaster

Tags: web-server, servo

I am trying to control a servo from a web service.
I have used [Springboot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and [ServoBlaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster) library.

Although [these ways to handle the servo](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/RaspiTests/blob/master/src/ServoControl.kt) work as a standalone application, nothing of the above works through `Springboot`.

I am running the application as root `./gradlew bootrun --no-daemon`. The handling of the other GPIOs is perfect.

Do I have to apply any weird setting at `Springboot`?

Should I access the servo pin differently?

Comment: I have never heard of Springboot.  For the sake of others and myself it would be useful if you added links to the items you are talking about.

Comment: @joan Edited with links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem was with the `servod` of the `ServoBlaster`. It was accidentally killed and I had to run it once again!

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352123/controlling-a-servo-at-raspberry-pi-with-springboot-and-servoblaster).